# How do I get Autobiographer Badge?

Tags: support, badges

I already have my profile info set but it's not giving me the badge on this Stack Exchange site.

I was able to get it on pretty much all other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fill in your age too...

Comment: Oh right got it thanks. :)

Comment: @puretppc: I'm sure you're aware of this, but once you get the badge, you can edit out those items you don't really want to be publicly visible without losing the badge.